# set AngularLocalForage in success login call

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, local-storage, localforage

I created token based authorization. After login, it stored token in localStorage but I realized that localStorage is synchronous and this is not what I want in my single page app. So I look into Angular Local Forage which as they say is async.

First I download localForage and angularLocalForage and add it in index

```
<script src="public/scripts/angular/localforage.js"></script>
<script src="public/scripts/angular/angular-localForage.js"></script>
```

next, I add the module in app.js

```
'LocalForageModule'
```

on success call in loginService i added following lines:

```
$localForage.set('authorization', {
    token: response.data.data.attributes.token,
    nick: 'other values..if neccessary'
});
```

and in my External Controller which wrap entire page I added `$localForage` get method:

```
'use strict';
app.controller('ExternalCtrl', ['$scope', '$localForage',
function($scope, $localForage) {

    $scope.authentication = {};

    $scope.authentication = {
        isAuth: false
    };

    var authData = $localForage.get('authorization');
    if(authData) {
        $scope.authentication.isAuth = true;
        console.log($scope.authentication.isAuth);
    }

}
]);
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work and makes all page doesn't show up it causes this error:

> TypeError: $localForage.get is not a function
>       at new  (ExternalCtrl.js:11)
>       at Object.invoke (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording the [doc](https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage)

There are no get() and set() method with localForage, should use use getItem() and setItem() and they are async, promise.

```
$localForage.setItem('authorization', {
    token: response.data.data.attributes.token,
    nick: 'other values..if neccessary'
}).then(function() {
    //logged and stored data
});
```

and

```
function loadData() {
    //here load data
}

$localForage.getItem('authorization').then(function(authData) {
    //we got a stored authData
    loadData();
}, function() {
    // not logged
});
```

Comment: Your solution is working but I still need to refresh page after logging and after logouting to see changes, why?

Comment: you need to redirect to the logged page only after the login service stored the data

Comment: But on my main page I have different things for logged people and not logged based on `$scope.authentication.isAuth = true;` and when I pass valid login and password I still have to refresh page in order to see stuff for logged users, how can I change it?

Comment: In this case (if you dont redirect after logining) you can make your initialization block in a function and call this function for every successfull login or logout..I'll update some example in my answers (eg: loadData() )

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand last your comment. I thing the problem is that `getItem()` in my External Ctrl maybe run async but only once when controller is loaded it is not watching on changes if the item im trying to get does still exist. I'm still looking for solution.

Comment: or been set up during the app working. That's why I still need to refresh.

Comment: @BT101 you just need to catch the login/logout call, then recall the service you want. If it's not possible for you AngularlocalForage has 2 events you can choose to be notified by broadcast on set and remove in localforage and use theses broadcast: https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage), the method for getting a value is `getItem()` and the method for setting values is `setItem()`.

Get item:

```
var authData = $localForage.getItem('authorization');
```

Set item:

```
$localForage.set('authorization', {
    token: response.data.data.attributes.token,
    nick: 'other values..if neccessary'
});
```